# modprobe nbd not releasing connection in Debian 10.2

Tags: debian, qemu, modprobe

**qemu-nbd** - QEMU Disk Network Block Device Server failing with Debian 10.2

Works perfect with Debian 9.12. Does not work any longer with Debian 10.2. Any suggestion of what I might be doing wrong?

```
modprobe nbd
qemu-nbd --connect /dev/nbd0 -f qcow2 /tmp/image.qcow2
# -----
qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
modprobe -r nbd
```

At the end it gives the following error message:
`modprobe: FATAL: Module nbd is in use.`
It works how it should in Debian 9.12. (Opens and closed the connection properly without leaving open connections).

In memory there are two processes open: **[kworker/u9:0-knbd0-recv]** and **[knbd0-recv]**

These two processes should be closed when executing `qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0`

[EDIT]
There is no `qemu-nbd` process running. 
The nbd device is still seen in /proc/partitions.

In `dmesg`:

```
 113.620404]  nbd0: p1 p2 < p5 >
[  117.767674] EXT4-fs (dm-10): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  156.688684] block nbd0: NBD_DISCONNECT
[  156.688696] block nbd0: Disconnected due to user request.
[  156.688697] block nbd0: shutting down sockets
[  163.869378] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nbd0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

This is what I see in the Debian 9.12 server with the same qcow2 image file:

```
[181586.110052] block nbd0: NBD_DISCONNECT
[181586.110063] block nbd0: shutting down sockets
[181617.936407]  nbd0: p1 p2 < p5 >
[181748.735336] EXT4-fs (dm-14): 6 orphan inodes deleted
[181748.735337] EXT4-fs (dm-14): recovery complete
[181748.755426] EXT4-fs (dm-14): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[181772.254622] block nbd0: NBD_DISCONNECT
```

[SOLUTION]
Make sure you execute `vgchange -a n nbdvg` before disconnecting.

Comment: No qemu-nbd process? The nbd device itself still in /proc/partitions? What happens when you try to read it? Anything in dmesg? Should be NBD_DISCONNECT, shutting down sockets or the like.

Comment: The nbd device is still in /proc/partitions. I see many errors with blk_update_request with dmesg  I/O error, dev nbd0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0. Thanks, I will update my question.

Comment: I have checked the physical disck with `smartctl` and has no errors. I have also passed `fsck` to the partitions in the qcow2 image file (two LVM2 partitions, root and swap)

Comment: Are those ext4 dm-10 messages random bystanders or do you have it mounted or other dependencies on that NBD device like LVM/cryptsetup/integrity/loop/mdadm devices, etc.? That could prevent the proper removal of the device. I can only guess at what the problem may be since it works just fine for me. For a quick check, `lsblk` might suffice, should have nothing under the nbd0 tree.

Comment: for LVM in particular you'd need a `vgchange -a n nbdvg` before disconnecting it. And these may be active unexpectedly as there's stuff with udev rules, lvmetad etc. happening in the background, so have to double check it's clear for removal

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. I was executing `vgchange -a n nbdvg` after the disconnecting. Funny this error was not showing in Debian 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using LVMs, execute `vgchange -a n nbdvg` before disconnecting:

this is the correct order:

```
modprobe nbd
qemu-nbd --connect /dev/nbd0 -f qcow2 /tmp/image.qcow2
# -----
vgchange -a n nbvg
qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
modprobe -r nbd
```

Comment: This same issue happens with one of my systems.  Use a process for customizing a vm clone image.  But, vgchange has no effect because the volume groups that exist in my qcow2 image don't show when I type vgdisplay.  This is still a problem and I bet it's a bug. `vgchange -a n $vgname` produces "Volume group "$vgname" not found"

Comment: As always I forgot to deactivate VGs before removing a device, that's a classic :-( And now I can't, I can't even do a `vgs` even that stall, can't even kill the `vgs` process.
Would it be safe to kill the `knbd0-recv` process? Maybe that will get things moving?

Comment: `knbd0-recv` is a kernel thread and it cannot be killed. Signals are difficult to deliver to kernel threads and in most cases this is not possible. In any case if this could be done it's not a good idea because if holding any resource it would not be released. In my case when I reach this point I have to reboot the server.

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting?  try the following in this order: 1) If mounted try to umount, 2) `vgchange -a n <vg_name>`  3) `qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0` 4) `nbd-client -d /dev/nbd0`, 5) `vgchange -ay`. After these 5 steps if still not working the only solution I found was reboot.